# Error - 403 forbidden on accessing my war deployed on web logic 9.x

Tags: java, ant, weblogic, war, http-status-code-403

1. I created a dynamic web project in Eclipse IDE.
2. Generated a build.xml for the dynamic web project.
3. Run build.xml to generate a war file(fip.war).
4. Deployed war on weblogic server 9.x

My web application does not contain **weblogic.xml**

There are no deployment errors in the console. But when I try to access my app
           **http://localhost:7001/fip**

I get **Error 403--Forbidden**

Since context root is not specified anywhere in my application, it will be taken from the name of the WAR file right?

Please let me know what needs to be set/added to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you try http://localhost:7001/fip/

Comment: I tried but I get - Error 403--Forbidden

Comment: You didn't set up welcome page list in web.xml, weblogic trying to show folder listing and get 403 error, because it is disabled by default. If you deploy your application on Tomcat, you get 404 error, Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/11026110/1516873