# Getting 403 forbidden when deploying and trying to access EAR file on WildFly

Tags: java, maven, jboss, wildfly, ear

First of all, none of the questions I found solved my issue. [Error - 403 forbidden on accessing my war deployed on web logic 9.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400438/error-403-forbidden-on-accessing-my-war-deployed-on-web-logic-9-x) comes near, but the solution recommended in the comments doesn't solve my issue, since my index.html and its assets were copy-pasted into the WEB-INF folder.

I deployed my application and I get 403 forbidden in the browser as if the index.html was missing, but it ain't.

I am using WildFly 15 and deploying from Eclipse 2022-06 if that matters.

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" version="4.0">
  <display-name>IdeaProjects</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>IdeaProjectsImport</groupId>
  <artifactId>IdeaProjectsImport</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2</version>
</plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <!-- MAVEN-ASSEMBLY -->
      <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.0</version>
      <configuration>
      <archive>
      <manifest>
      <mainClass>VorlagenWerkWebService.VorlagenWerkService.src.main.java.com.example.vorlagenwerk.HelloWorldServiceImpl</mainClass></manifest></archive></configuration>
      <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>make-assembly</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution></executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: "since my index.html and its assets were copy-pasted into the WEB-INF folder" -> Are you saying your `index.html` page is in the `WAR.war/WEB-INF` directory? If so that is not the correct directory. It needs to be in the root if it's just a static HTML page.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins tried that, now I'm getting 404, which is even worse...

Comment: It's tough to tell what it might be without more information about the project. Static HTML should not be in the `WEB-INF`. The POM configuration looks a little odd, but I don't really know your project configuration. Normally resources would be in `src/main/resources`.